# What Neural Network solution(s) are appropriate for time series regression with delays?

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, regression, timedelay

I'm trying to find the best type of neural network for time series regression. I would describe my scenario this way:

- I have 1D time series data from sensors A, B, C, D, E and F.
- I'm trying to generate a regression model for sensor F data, by using data from A-E sensors.
- I know that for some sensors, I need to take in account the last X hours of data in order to have a proper model. This "delay" is different for every sensor (for example, I need to use the last 6 hours from sensor A-B, the last 30 mins for C-E), but consistent over time.
- I have an approximative estimation of the max "delays", but I do not know them precisely for every sensor (which prevents me to preprocess my data).

My goal is to be able to produce a model/network trained on data of all sensors, and then apply it to new data from A-E and compare my regression results with actual data (from sensor F in this case).

Before this, I have been using Time Delay Neural Networks with MATLAB but this approach did not allow me much flexibility over the design of a network. By doing some research on vulgarization websites, I found many people comparing Time Delay Neural Networks and Recursive Neural Networks. However, while the MATLAB quick documentation made me think that I understood how these networks work, I am now a bit confused with various (and sometime contradictory) opinions on the subject.

What would be the appropriate types of Neural Networks for my problem ? Should I transform my data ? (for example, instead of 1d data, using time segments of the past X hours at each timestamp ?)
I would gladly accept any reference/book for better understanding.

Comment: You probably will want to use a modern recurrent network architecture, like LSTM or derivatives. Those store a "state" computed from the input sequence and are able to learn to "remember" very long dependencies. The question is kind of offtopic for Stack Overflow though (it's more about machine learning as a science than programming itself), and a bit too broad too.

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you for response. Apologies if offtopic for SO, I was focused on Tensorflow and got redirected here. I will try to improve the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

For time series predictions are usually used:

- [Radial basis function networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network).-The network input are past states over the time series, the output is a prediction for future states. This ones are simple and easy to build.
- [Recurrent neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network).- Harder to build, but are prepared to work with dynamic behaviors.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I did not know about Radial basis function networks. Considering another suggestion in the comments, it seems I should also focus on RNN/LSTM.